# Can not find the stored procedure error in SQL Server Agent job with ssis package

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

An SSIS package which consists of an Execute SQL task is running fine when executed in the SQL Server 2014 catalog.

When this is a part of a SQL Server agent job, it throws an error

> can not find the stored procedure

The package's Execute SQL task contains the statement

```
exec usp_procedures
```

The definition of this stored procedure is to execute multiple other stored procedures:

```
exec usp_strdproc1
exec usp_strdproc2
exec usp_strdproc3
exec usp_strdproc4
```

All of the sub procedures are accessing files in a particular location. I have ensured that the SQL Server agent job has all the permission to access the file

Comment: Are you sure you're runnig job on correct database?

Comment: sorry.could not understand the question

Comment: there is only 1 step in the job ,it is of the type ssis package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would immediately think its a permission issue, but you have checked that.

Next check what schema you should be using and whether thats set up correctly?

Is the SQL Server Job Agent running on the same server?

Have you pointed the job to the correct database?

Hope this points you in the right direction.